# spacebar not cancelling default event on firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm building a video player and one of the features is related to toggle play when I hit spacebar and execute a process within. It works on all browsers except Firefox. If I hit spacebar and the video is paused, it plays for less than a second and immediately gets paused. Is there something I'm not aware of that is causing this behavior that is only related to Firefox?

```
player.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 32) {
      if (player.paused) {
         player.play();
      } else {
         player.pause();
      }

     // ... other actions with this event

     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();
   }
}, false);
```

Comment: `attachEventListener` ? What API is this?

Comment: My bad. I edited the code; it should have been ```addEventListener```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox triggers a click event when using space bar. So using a conditional to avoid Firefox when pressing space bar fixes it